# How to call a stored procedure in JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, plsql

For homework I have to create a pl/sql stored procedure to add a facutly member to a database

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADDFACULTYDEPTSAL
  (facid IN NUMBER,
  facname IN VARCHAR,
  depID IN NUMBER)
AS
  sal NUMBER;
BEGIN
  CALCSALDEPT(depID, sal);
  IF sal >= 50000
  THEN 
    sal := sal*.9;
  ELSE
    IF sal >= 30000
    THEN
      sal := sal*.8;
    END IF;
  END IF;

  INSERT INTO FACULTY(fid, fname, deptid, salary)
  VALUES(facid, facname, depID, sal);
END ADDFACULTYDEPTSAL;
```

Having done that, I need to make a java call for said procedure, which I've tired to do with:

```
Statement stmt = dbConnection.createStatement();
String in;
if(a == 1){
    in = "ADDFACULTYDEPTSAL("
        + fid.getText() + "','"
        + fname.getText() + "','"
        + did.getText() + "')";
} else {
    in = "ADDFACULTYUNISAL("
        + fid.getText() + "','"
        + fname.getText() + "','"
        + did.getText() + "')";
}
stmt.executeQuery(in);
```

I have the above in a try catch block that keeps throwing an error.  I have tried several variants on the string "in" based on what I saw on other websites:
    in = "{call ADDFACULTYDEPSAL ...
    in = "call ADDFACULTYDEPSAL ...

looking here: [MySQL Connector Guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-statements-callable.html)
I also tried changing stmt to a callable statement as such:

```
CallableStatement stmt;
if(a == 1){
    stmt = dbConnection.prepareCall("{call ADDFACULTYDEPTSAL(?,?,?)}");
} else {
    stmt = dbConnection.prepareCall("{call ADDFACULTYUNISAL(?,?,?)}");
}
```

However, trying this way doesn't seem to work because I need to pass more than two variables into the procedure.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
String call = (a == 1 ? "{call ADDFACULTYDEPTSAL(?,?,?)}"
                      : "{call ADDFACULTYUNISAL(?,?,?)}");
try (CallableStatement stmt = dbConnection.prepareCall(call)) {
    stmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(fid.getText()));
    stmt.setString(2, fname.getText());
    stmt.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(did.getText()));
    stmt.execute();
}
```

Comment: @Andreas, Good explanation. However, Could you suggest me how to store and fetch the result of the stored procedure using java?