# Run PL/pgSQL script using java

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, plpgsql

It is possible to run PL/pgSQL script using java? I'm creating postgres db from java code and need creating some functions on this db.

I know I can run any sql script using DriverManager like that:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
              connectionToDbUrl,
              getDbUser(),
              getDbPassword());
Statement statement = connection.createStatement()
statement.execute("select * from table);
```

but it will not execute PL/pgSQL script. Any ideas?

EDIT: I mean PL/pgSQL

EDIT 2: I found bug thanks @a_horse_with_no_name solution.
I read script from file using BufferedReader and join all lines. Adding " \n" on end of each line solves problem.

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(resource.getFile())))
    {
    statement.execute(br.lines().collect(Collectors.joining(" \n")));
    }
```

Comment: Did you mean [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql.html) ?

Comment: PSQL is basically a shell or a terminal for Postgres, with lots of proprietary syntax.  I'd assume you could basically pull up a command shell from within your java program, but you'd be better off writing actual SQL and running that thru JDBC.

Comment: @Aaron yes, I mean PL/pgSQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I want create function on new db, not run one

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name how exacly? Running by statement.execute throws exception when script is in PL/pgSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres", "...", "******");

Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

String create =
  "create function the_answer() \n" +
  "returns integer as $$\n" +
  "begin \n" +
  "   return 42;\n" +
  "end;\n" +
  "$$\n" +
  "language plpgsql;";

// create the function
stmt.execute(create);

// use the function
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select the_answer()");
rs.next();
System.out.println("The answer is: " + rs.getInt(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to PostgreSQL JDBC documentation for that:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/jdbc-callproc.html

In case your pgSQL returns a value call it like that:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM your_func()");
```

Answer (score 0):

PL/pgSQL is a special case of calling a stored procedure (or function or package).

You must use [CallableStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) adding de corresponding parameters. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33061599/16206) example.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue, but I got to solve it in a slightly different way which I wish to share here for anyone else.

I found using the JDBC approach rather clumsy. I wanted to use an approach as close to using pgqsl from the terminal as possible.

**Requirement 1**: As a prerequisite to using this approach, you should be able to run pgsql command for the terminal already.

**Requirement 2**: The file .pgpass in a user's home directory or the file referenced by PGPASSFILE can contain passwords to be used if the connection requires a password (and no password has been specified otherwise). This file should contain lines of the following format:

`hostname:port:database:username:password`

So create a file **.pgpass** in your home directory (or wherever else you may feel like actually since you'll need to reference this location later anyway)

**Requirement 3**: .pgpass requires restricted access, otherwise you will get this error - `.pgpass" has group or world access; permissions should be u=rw (0600) or less`. To fix this, just chmod the file to at least 600 `chmod 600 ~/.pgpass`

**Requirement 4**: Add this piece of java code to execute your sql script. Substitute <username>, <hostname> and <database> with the values you used in the **.pgpass** file

```
System.setProperty("PGPASSFILE", "~/.pgpass");
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("psql -U <username> -h <hostname> -d <database> -f src/main/resources/schema.sql");
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
        int ret = process.waitFor();
        System.out.printf("Program exited with code: %d%n", ret);
```

And that should do it for you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the explain about buid, install and use PL/JAVA for PostgreSql:

https://tada.github.io/pljava/

And here is an example 'hello world' about it:

https://tada.github.io/pljava/use/hello.html

Comment: Please ensure that your answer will still make sense even if the links got removed or outdated.